# Combining goals in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I track several different goals in analytics. Two of my goals are:
A - an event
B - a pageview

I want to know how many (in %) of my visitors, that completed A also completed B.
As I understand funnels, goals have to be tracked in a certain order, which is not the case here. Is there another way to accomplish this or have I just misunderstood funnels? Can I calculate this data retroactively on old sessions?

Comment: You probably wouldn't use goals for this (you cannot really "combine" goals, a goal is either an event or a pageview. Also it seems you do not quite understand how funnels in GA work.), instead you would create a segment with two conditions and apply it to the audience report.

Comment: Segments were the way to go. Creating a segment with one goal I could see how that segment performed on my other goal in the "Goals" section. Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Borje How do you create a segment of users who created a goal?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah What do you mean by users who created a goal? You create goals and then segment users on the goals you created. Users don't create goals.

Comment: @Borje Yes, I mean't how do you create a segment that only contains a site's visitors who triggered one or more goals?